# How to access IWiaItemExtras interface

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, com, wia

I'm recently developing an application to connect to PTP cameras and send out vendor-specific PTP commands to control the camera.
However, I'm new to c# and VS, so by only including the WIA reference, I'm still unable to access the IWiaItemExtras::Escape method to send generic commands (VS said there is no such function). On the Microsoft page, it said:

> By calling QueryInterface on the root item, you can retrieve a pointer to the IWiaItemExtras interface.

I looked around the website, it didn't say what to include as a reference. It only said that it inherits from IUnknown, a COM fundamental interface.

So what do I need to include so I can access the interface & the method?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you get it to work? I can read device info etc but i'm not sure how i can actually get the IWiaItemExtras interface.